# Different drop directory by Platform for TFS Builds

Tags: c++, tfs, msbuild

We have a C++ solution where a few of our projects require a 64 bit build in addition to our normal 32 bit build.

We encounter a problem with our TFS builds since it wants to drop everything into a single folder.

We have a work around where we change the output path in project properties -> linker -> general -> Output File to $(OutDir)**x64/**$(TargetName)$(TargetExt) in our 64 bit configuration (change is bolded).  However when we build we get a warning that our project has build to a different folder than expected.  We'd like to get rid of this warning and use a less hacky approach.

Building multiple platforms seems like it would be a common occurrence, is there an normal way people get around this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Usually you set the **AsConfigured** option and add a script to move the binaries to the final location in the Drop folder.

Details and sample scripts in [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/07/24/basic-tfbuild-scripts.aspx).